# Starting bash on linux ubuntu with Android

Tags: 14.04, server

anyone knows if you can start bash script from Android to linux remotely . I've tried using vnc but are not interested in viewing the screen but simply to send the command to start remote Android

Answer (score 0):

For me looks like you want `ssh linux-user@linux-host "your script"` from Android.
This will need installation of ssh client on Android device. Somehow ssh client must be compiled for particular hardware / Linux kernel of the Android device.

Alternative is to find Java ssh client library that provides command execution and write Android app for this.

If your goal is to run custom scripts occasionally (manually typing host/user/password/script name) then there are lot of ssh terminals in android appstores, starting from google play. Just expose sshd at linux machine.